# What are the [meeting] and [meeting-request] tags for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both [meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting) and [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request) lack summaries, wiki pages, and synonyms. They mainly seem to be used for Outlook (or SharePoint) questions, although this is not *always* the case:

- [meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting) - [Orange County .NET Developers Meetings/ Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437223/4200092)
- [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request) - [OO implementation of RFC 2445](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2665248/4200092)

What should we do with these tags?

1. Keep them both, and make them synonyms.
2. Keep the best<sup>1</sup> one, and get rid of the other.
3. [Burn everything](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=MGS3+The+Fury+!gi).

Assuming that at least one of them is kept, we should add tag wiki information to clarify what (its/their) intended purpose is.

---

<sup>1. Definition of the word "best" in this instance is left as an excercise for the reader.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The majority of what I see revolves around meeting requests, so I would vote to keep [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request) and alias [meeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting) to it. Meeting Request is more descriptive and tells the whole story. Just "meeting" can get stuck to things that tend to be off-topic (i.e. your first link).

The wiki page for [meeting-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meeting-request) should be generic enough to not limit itself to just SharePoint or Exchange, as I see some other platforms (iCal, GoToMeeting, etc.) as well.

Comment: The [tag:meeting-request] wiki has been updated to be platform-independent, by referring to the EVENT component of RFC-5545.